# Pulling external PCB pin low via NPN transistor. How does it work?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switching

I am redesigning a PCB which hosts an ESP32 and a display connector. One of the pins in this display connector needs to be pulled low or high.

On the other side (display) that pin is connected to an STM32 and I'm not sure what it does.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqTM53.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've simulated the ESP32 with V1 and the 3.3 src from the STM32 with V2. R1 is present on original board and Q1 is actually an S8050 (J3Y marking on top).

If I run simulation:

- When logic level is 0 => all good
- When logic level is high => a lot of current is drawn from V1 to Emitter.GND.

As far as I know the ESP32 has 20 mA max per pin so maybe there is something else I don't see that is limiting the current? Or maybe my diagram is wrong.

Since i dont really know how to represent STM32 input pin i just added a 3v3 voltage source (V2). Not sure if there is a better way to represent it.

Here's a pic of the real PCB.
[image]

Edit: fixed image.

Comment: The base-emitter junction is essentially a forward biased diode. That's why you're drawing a load of current from V1. Use a series resistor to limit the current.

Comment: Andrea Baccega - Hi, FYI more context is needed & (IMHO) too much is being assumed (or at least, not explained) making the reverse-engineering question difficult. Just two examples: (a) You said you don't know what the STM32 does (on some kind of display not shown in the question?) yet the schematic shows it as a voltage source. How do you know that STM32 pin is an o/p (as a voltage source would imply) and not an i/p (which would make more sense with the schematic you drew)? (b) Are you 100% *sure* the IOG (??) signal goes directly to the BJT base? The PCB photo isn't clear. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, what is that display pin's function? If your schematic is correct then the only thing I can imagine is that it is the cathode of a back light led which is driven by PWM to control the display brightness. Otherwise,  I can't see why it would be necessary to design the circuit with an NPN transistor to sink such a  current which is clearly too large for a GPIO pin.

Comment: @SamGibson I'm guessing that "IOG" is actually 104 indicating a 10k base current limiting resistor which gives me the opportunity to point out that it is missing from the schematic.

Comment: @6v6gt - Hi, "*I'm guessing that "IOG" is actually 104*" Interesting - I would never have guessed that possibility. || I'm hoping the OP will add *lots* more detail. Currently, I suspect there may be incorrect assumptions in the question/diagram, which the OP seems to suggest is a possibility. || Reverse-engineering questions like this do need to have accurate information, to avoid people wasting time...

Comment: Hey all, i updated the schematic + image to HOPEFULLY better represent what is going on on the pcb.

Comment: The schematic gets even more confusing. Did you mean that R2 should be a pullup resistor or is it in in series with the connection V1 / Q1 base ?
As it appears, there is still no base current limiting resistor so you will still see the high current usage you already reported.
If there is now a 10k resistor between Vcc and the display pin then I withdraw the suggestion that the pin could be a back light LED for the display.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in simulation a lot of current will be drawn by V1.
You would normally place a series resistor between V1 and Q1 to limit the current or a voltage divider where you again have a series resistor between V1 and Q1 and then a resistor in parallel with Q1. This will limit your current.

In your simulation, you apply 3.3V as Vbe for Q1 which is equal to almost “infinite” amount of current

Yes the microcontroller cannot supply this very high current you see in simulation, but good practice is to do as described above.

Comment: just to properly make sure i understand. The fact that the original board works is thanks to the esp32 limiting the current?

Comment: Yes I would suspect it limits the current.